# How to enable CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse() and @EnableJdbcHttpSession?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-session, spring-authorization-server

I have a Spring boot application with Spring Authorization Server (the new 4.0.1 package [Spring Authorization](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/0.4.x))

The server is in a cluster of servers thus it needs to save the session in a DB so I use @EnableJdbcHttpSession.
The Authorization service has state change request (e.g login etc...) with HTTP POST called from client written in Angular JS.
In order to secure my HTTP POST requests I use csrf e.g.  csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())

Its seems that @EnableJdbcHttpSession invoke the HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository so I can't define the post request to work with CookieCsrfTokenRepository.

When I define CookieCsrfTokenRepository the SESSION cookie is not getting created, is it possible to define both somehow ?

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class SecurityConfiguration {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http
      .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
          authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
      ).formLogin(withDefaults())

      .csrf()
      .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())

  return http.build();
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will fix the issue

```
http.sessionManagement(session ->      session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS))
```